# Remove auto search from text box and search upon search button

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using the jQuery datatables and I am trying to figure out how to have my search search from a "search button" and not automatically from the textbox.

I am writing a single page application so there are more than one submit button which makes this difficult because I only want it to search from that specific search button and not upon submit to trigger the other submit buttons.

I googled it and none of the results were successful. How do you grab the value from the input upon submit of the search button in order to adjust the datatable correctly.

Then I want the search button to change the text to exit search to put the datatable back to its normal state as if you were to just delete the text from the textbox. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

JS

```
// Search Mode allows to search tables
    $("#Search").on("click",function(){
        $("#ItemID").prop("disabled", false);
        $("#ESearch").show();
        $("#Search").hide();

      // Allows ItemID to search through database
      $('#ItemID').keyup(function(){
        oTable.search($(this).val()).draw() ;
      });

    });

    // Exit out of EXIT SEARCH mode
    $("#ESearch").on("click",function(){
        $("#ItemID").val("");
        $("#ItemID").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#Search").show();
        $("#ESearch").hide();
    });
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="ItemID" id="ItemID" maxlength="15"> 
<span class="input-group-btn">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="Search">SEARCH</button>
<button style="display:none;" type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="ESearch">EXIT SEARCH</button>
</span>
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There is no reason for adding a new search `<input>`, you can reuse the default. The below code resets the default search / filtering that happens when you type in the default `<input>` box, then adds two buttons that performs / clear the search / filtering upon click.

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    initComplete : function() {
        var input = $('.dataTables_filter input').unbind(),
            self = this.api(),
            $searchButton = $('<button>')
                       .text('search')
                       .click(function() {
                          self.search(input.val()).draw();
                       }),
            $clearButton = $('<button>')
                       .text('clear')
                       .click(function() {
                          input.val('');
                          $searchButton.click(); 
                       }) 
        $('.dataTables_filter').append($searchButton, $clearButton);
    }            
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/zuv05qbj/**

Comment: great solution. Thanks

Comment: great solution !!  but for me, the newly added buttons are placed on the left side (before) of the search box. had to make some changes in append code.                                                                                                        
  var $searchDivParent = $('#example_filter').parent();
  $searchDivParent.append( $clearButton,$searchButton, $('#example_filter'));

Comment: Perfect although I needed to chnage the click event to stop the page submitting.  .click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); did the trick.

Answer (score 5):

And as with davids amazing answer, you can also bind the ENTER key to perform the search as well, by invoking the search button click event when it is pressed:

```
initComplete : function() {
    var self = this.api();
    var filter_input = $('#'+settings.nTableWrapper.id+' .dataTables_filter input').unbind();
    var search_button = $('<button type="button">Search</button>').click(function() {
        self.search(filter_input.val()).draw();
    });
    var clear_button = $('<button type="button">Clear</button>').click(function() {
        filter_input.val('');
        search_button.click();
    });

    $(document).keypress(function (event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            search_button.click();
        }
    });

    $('#'+settings.nTableWrapper.id+' .dataTables_filter').append(search_button, clear_button);
}
```

Works if you have multiple datatables on the page too :) (note the use of `settings.nTableWrapper.id`)

Comment: change `$(document).keypress` to `filter_input.keypress`. to trigger `enter` only on current focused search input if you have multiple datatables on one page

Answer (score 2):

Just implemented this and it works great. I added an icon button and some simple flex css to make them inline.

```
var input = $('.dataTables_filter input').unbind(),
self = this.api(),
      $searchButton = $(`<button type="submit" 
                              class="btn btn-inverse dtSearchButton" 
                              id="button_search" 
                              data-toggle="tooltip" 
                              title="Apply Search"
                              style="padding:0,5px,0,5px"
                      >
                      <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                      </button>`)
                  .click(function() {
                    self.search(input.val()).draw();
                  }),
      $clearButton = $(`<button 
                          type="button" 
                          class="btn btn-inverse dtSearchButton" 
                          id="button_trash" 
                          data-toggle="tooltip" 
                          title="Clear Search"
                          style="padding:0,5px,0,5px"
                        >
                        <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
                        </button>`)
                .click(function() {
                    input.val('');
                    $searchButton.click(); 
                }) 
      
      $('.dataTables_filter').append($searchButton, $clearButton);
```

then in css:

```
.dataTables_filter{
  display:flex;
}
```

final output
[image: Final Output]